# AJAX get requests with parameters fail (i.e., don't send)

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

This works:

```
$.get("/users/iq_leaderboard")
```

but this fails – in fact jQuery doesn't even send the request in this case:

```
$.get("/users/iq_leaderboard?interval=week")
```

Check it out:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2792776/screenshots/2012-04-17_2055.png

oddly if I add a success callback it will fire (even though the request doesn't send). This problem persists for all GET requests with parameters

Comment: could be your server side language that doesn't handle GET request properly :o, did you check that?

Comment: How's your server side? The request in ok in you jQuery. You could be more specific and launch a $.ajax or $.getJSON if you want some JSON... As far as I see, you're note getting a 200 status, so it means that there's something on your server side.

Comment: the request isn't even reaching the server. it behaves exactly the same when the server isn't even running lol!

Comment: You may paste some of your server-side code here. It's reaching something because if it wasn't, there'd be a 404 code instead of (failed).

Answer (score 3):

First, check your server side. If it's ok, do it the right way:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/users/iq_leaderboard",
    data: {
        interval: "week"
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data); // to debug only
    },
    dataType: "json" // in case you're returning json
});
```

Try that.

Answer (score 0):

I always do it like this

```
$.get("/users/iq_leaderboard",{interval:week},function(data){});
```